# Why 'verify' in unit tests does not return 'different arguments' error in case of different instances?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Let's take a look at this example:

```
@Test
@SneakyThrows
public void shouldSave(){
    //given
    String filename = "exampleName";
    String filenameWithExtension = "exampleName.jpg";
    InputStream inputStream = IOUtils.toInputStream("exampleInputStream", "UTF-8");

    //when
    storageImageRepository.save(filename, inputStream);

    //then
    verify(storageRepository).store(new StorageMetadata(filenameWithExtension), inputStream);
}
```

Verify returns "different arguments" error here and that's expected because new instance of StorageMetadata is created inside storageImageRepostiory.save() method to call storageRepository.store(). Everything's fine so far, I can create ArgumentCaptor, use it in verify and everyone's happy.

However, take a look at this:

```
@Test
public void shouldGetMediaObject(){
    //given
    when(mediaObjectRepository.getMediaObject(new MediaObjectCriteria("1"))).thenReturn(pojoMediaObject);

    //when
    MediaObjectTO result = mainMediaObjectService.getMediaObject("1");

    //then
    verify(mediaObjectRepository).getMediaObject(new MediaObjectCriteria("1"));
}
```

Here we have a mocked getMediaObject() repository method that returns predefined object (pojoMediaObject) when the argument is MediaObjectCriteria with ID 1.

Now, when I call mainMediaObjectService.getMediaObject("1"), it creates new instance of MediaObjectCriteria with id passed in parameter (which in this case is 1 as well) and calls mocked repository method.

The question is: Why this test passes? Shouldn't verify return "different arguments" error? There are 3 different instances of MediaObjectCritera. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does `MediaObjectCriteria` override `equals`?

Comment: Yes, it has @Data annotation from Project Lombok. Holy moly, that simple comment made me understand everything. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was quick. Turns out `MediaObjectCritera` had `@Data` annotation (Lombok) which overrides `equals` method.

Thanks to **@chrylis** for quick and spot on comment.